# Factor $x^6+\dots+1$ over $\mathbb R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus

Out of idle curiosity, while teaching Calculus II, I started to wonder about this:

How do you factor the polynomial
$$
f_6(x)=x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1
$$
into quadratic and linear factors over $\mathbb R$?

I know how to do it for $f_5$ (defined in the obvious way), $f_4$, and lower.

Comment: You should be able to realize that the roots are the seventh roots of $1$ (distinct from $1$).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$f_6(x)=\frac{x^7-1}{x-1}=\prod_{k=1}^{3}\left(x^2-2x\cos\frac{2k\pi}{7}+1\right).$$

Answer (score 6):

The polynomial is $\dfrac{x^7-1}{x-1}$, so its roots are
$$
\cos\frac{2k\pi}{7}+i\sin\frac{2k\pi}{7}\qquad (k=1,2,3,4,5,6)
$$
Determine the conjugate pairs and you're done.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, thanks